# Executing a sql script every month for the first and last 16 days.

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a script that I have had to ran manually a few times but now it looks like it will need to be ran twice a month. The problem is the dates are dynamic and the job needs to run on the 1st and 16th of every month but it will need to pull all data from the last 16 days. So for example, if we run it on the first of this month (Jan) the dates would be >= 2016-12,16 and <= 2016-12-31

I have been looking at the date function sql server has but I am not really sure if it will work for what I need.

Comment: Have you looked at `datediff` and `eomonth`?

Comment: What does "looking at the date function" mean?   What have you tried, and what errors did you get?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at DateAdd, and add a negative number of dates to the value to go back 16 days.

```
DATEADD(DAY, -16, GETDATE()).
```

I would personally just run a script with cron and set it up to run on the 1st and the 16th of every month.

Comment: Thanks Loaf, this is exactly what I was looking for.